# waff wiki function in ns-3 does not get parameters

Tags: waf, ns-3

In **ns-3** simulator [documentation](http://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.21/tutorial/singlehtml/index.html#building-ns3) they provide a simple bash function to ease your life:

```
function waff {
   CWD="$PWD"
   cd $NS3DIR
   ./waf --cwd="$CWD" $*
   cd -
}
```

This function is supposed to execute the **./waf** program situated in the ns-3 root folder but inside the folder you are actually situated into.

So in the case of `~/project$ waff --run first` waf will run the **first** script in the **~/project** folder.

But if I try to run any simulation by adding one parameter to the script's command like `~/project$ waff --run "first --PrintHelp"` it throws an error

`waf: error: no such option: --PrintHelp`.

It only works when I actually run the scripts from the root folder without the **waff** function.

How to modify the function to make it expand the $* to an argument between double commas?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I feel embarrased because the solution was way easier than expected.

If anyone using DCE has the same problem, it's as easy as quoting the $*:

```
./waf --cwd="$CWD" $*
```

with:

```
./waf --cwd="$CWD" "$*"
```

Comment: What is DCE by the way?

Comment: Yes sorry, DCE is Direct Code Execution. It's a framework that allows to run native executables inside the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

This function works for me with bash (supposed you defined the environment variable $NS3DIR) :

```
function waff {
CWD="$PWD"
cd $NS3DIR >/dev/null
./waf --cwd="$CWD" "$@"
cd - >/dev/null
}
```

Proof it works is :

```
$ waff --run "wifi-simple-adhoc --help"
Waf: Entering directory `/home'
Waf: Leaving directory `/home'
'build' finished successfully (2.013s)
ns3.22-wifi-simple-adhoc-debug [Program Arguments] [General Arguments]

Program Arguments:
    --phyMode:     Wifi Phy mode [DsssRate1Mbps]
    --rss:         received signal strength [-80]
    --packetSize:  size of application packet sent [1000]
    --numPackets:  number of packets generated [1]
    --interval:    interval (seconds) between packets [1]
    --verbose:     turn on all WifiNetDevice log components [false]

General Arguments:
    --PrintGlobals:              Print the list of globals.
    --PrintGroups:               Print the list of groups.
    --PrintGroup=[group]:        Print all TypeIds of group.
    --PrintTypeIds:              Print all TypeIds.
    --PrintAttributes=[typeid]:  Print all attributes of typeid.
    --PrintHelp:                 Print this help message.

$ waff --run wifi-simple-adhoc --command-template=" %s --help"
Waf: Entering directory `/home'
Waf: Leaving directory `/home'
'build' finished successfully (1.816s)
ns3.22-wifi-simple-adhoc-debug [Program Arguments] [General Arguments]

Program Arguments:
    --phyMode:     Wifi Phy mode [DsssRate1Mbps]
    --rss:         received signal strength [-80]
    --packetSize:  size of application packet sent [1000]
    --numPackets:  number of packets generated [1]
    --interval:    interval (seconds) between packets [1]
    --verbose:     turn on all WifiNetDevice log components [false]

General Arguments:
    --PrintGlobals:              Print the list of globals.
    --PrintGroups:               Print the list of groups.
    --PrintGroup=[group]:        Print all TypeIds of group.
    --PrintTypeIds:              Print all TypeIds.
    --PrintAttributes=[typeid]:  Print all attributes of typeid.
    --PrintHelp:                 Print this help message.
```